# Vue.js & Django - axios post response status 200 but called catch error

Tags: api, vue.js, error-handling, axios

i'm learning Vue.js and Django.
I want to post user info.
axios response status 200 code, but catch function is called.

If the response is successful, the login 'success dialog' is called , but the login 'fail dialog' is also called.
this image is console log.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KtQQ.png)

please help me!

here is my code.

```js
<script>
// LoginDialog.vue
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";

export default {
  name: "LoginDialog",
  components: {},

  props: {
    dialog: Boolean,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      showPassword: false,
      dialogClose: {
        success: false,
        fail: false,
      },
      me: {},
    };
  },
  setup() {},
  created() {},

  mounted() {},
  unmounted() {},

  computed: {
    dialogOpen: {
      get() {
        return this.dialog;
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("close", val);
      },
    },
  },

  methods: {
    save() {
      console.log("save()...");
      const postData = new FormData(document.getElementById("login-from"));
      axios
        .post("/api/login/", postData)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("LOGIN POST RES", res);
          // alert(`user ${res.data.username} login OK`);
          this.dialogClose.success = true;
          this.this.me = res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("LOGIN POST ERR.RESPONSE", err.response);
          this.dialogClose.fail = true;
          // alert("login FAIL");
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
// LoginDialog.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- 로그인 dialog -->
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogOpen" max-width="500">
      <v-card width="800" class="mx-auto mt-5">
        <v-toolbar color="primary" dark flat>
          <v-toolbar-title class="pb-0">
            <h2>Login</h2>
          </v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form id="login-from" ref="loginForm">
            <v-text-field
              label="Username"
              name="username"
              prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
              :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
              prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
              :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
              @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
              autocomplete="on"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            text
            color="grey"
            center
            @click="(dialogOpen = false), $refs.loginForm.reset()"
            >Cancel</v-btn
          >
          <v-btn color="success" center @click="dialogOpen = false"
            >Register</v-btn
          >
          <v-btn color="info" center @click="save()">Login</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

    <!-- login success 팝업창 -->
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogClose.success" max-width="290">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h5"> Login Success! </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="green darken-1"
            text
            @click="dialogClose.success = false"
          >
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

    <!-- login fail 팝업창 -->
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogClose.fail" max-width="290">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h5"> Login Fail! </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialogClose.fail = false">
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: can you try to print the err not the err.response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Axios call goes well, but after that, in the `.then` block an error is thrown and caught by the `.catch` block. This is also why the `err.response` is empty, [because that is an error object of Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors). If you log the `err` instead of `err.response` you might see the actual error (as Akzhol Kadylbek suggested in his comment).

Looking at your code, I presume that error comes from this line:

```
this.this.me = res.data;
/// change to this.me = res.data;
```

The double `this.` looks like a typo.

Hope this helps.